# Copy file and metadata to library having event handler timing problem

Tags: workflow, event-receivers

Using SP2010, I have a custom workflow (Visual Studio) that copies an Approved file from library A to library B (within the same site collection).  I found that I must do the copy in two steps to handle any file type: (1) copy the file to Lib B (CopyTo method), (2) then copy the metadata to the newly created file in lib B.  If we used only MS Office products, the metadata goes with the file automatically and could be reduced to only one step, but alas, we allow PDF, txt, etc., so no metadata gets copied automatically, thus the need to copy the metadata programmatically in the WF.  The WF has been working fine for several years.

Now, in lib B, I need to create an event handler that needs to do some stuff, among other things is send an email out.  But, I need the metadata of the file to be able to send the email to proper person.  The problem is that I can't rely on the WF from Lib A to finish it's copying of the metadata before my EH in Lib B fires, and so I get an error attempting to use a metadata value that is still null.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?  How can I trigger an event in Lib B yet reliably know that the WF in Lib A has completed?  Or is there a better design than what I'm attempting.  The basic task is copy file to Lib B when file is Approved in Lib A (we set Content Approval required in Lib A), and automatically send out email (and other stuff) when that file arrives in Lib B, but email depends on metadata of the file coming from Lib A.

Thanks for any help,
KevinHou